# Remove screwdriver tip from screw hole

Tags: screws, screwdriver, stuck

Gonna be a weird one. I've tried to open up a Neato Robot Vacuum to fix a small problem and I've found myself in a doozy. Trying to unscrew it, the tip of the screwdriver must have been loose and fell into a screw hole. The problem is that it won't come out now.. I've tried grabbing it with a pair of pliers but it's too much of a tight fit, I've tried shaking the hell out of it and bumping the other side but it seems to be really stuck in there. Any ideas?

[image: here's the litter bugger along one of its siblings for reference]

Comment: Are we taking about the round looking thing in the near center of the photograph (that doesn't look like a bit) or are we talking about the thing to the left that looks hexagonal like a bit?? The left one, just grab with plyers3

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a strong magnet? Most of my drivers that use those small bits hold them in place with a magnet so the bit becomes magnetic. A strong magnet may take it right out where shaking won’t.

Comment: Take an old hard drive apart.... strongest magnets I ever saw.. except the ones that lift cars..lol+

Answer (score 2):

If the magnet doesn't work, try putting a drop of super or crazy glue on the bit and then sticking a doll rod on top of it... wait for the glue to dry and then pull out. be careful not to allow the glue to slip into the cracks. you could also use quick drying epoxy.

Comment: I agree super glue would be my next step I wold clean the screwdriver end off put the glue on the dowel or whatever let it set and give it a try.

Comment: super glue gel, not liquid